# Unable to reference $ref schema from different file

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, json.net

**How do I reference a schema from a different file?**

I am getting the following warning in Visual Studio when attempting to `$ref` a schema:

> The type of schema applied to the document is not supported.

I am attempting to use `JSchema`:

```
                var schema = JSchema.Parse(@"{
  '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#',
  'properties': {
                    'address': {
                        '$ref': 'MyOtherFile.Address.json#/definitions/address'
                    }
                }
            }
            ");
```

And the contents of `MyOtherFile.Address.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "title": "Address",
      "addressLine1": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "addressLine2": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "country": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "state": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what it looks like from VS:

[image: Here's the output from Visual Studio.]

**What am I doing wrong? How do I reference a schema from a different file?**

Comment: very much appreciated, @kiran shahi for including that image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/LoadingSchemas.htm), you must add a parameter (`JSchemaUrlResolver()`) to the call to `JSchema.Parse` in order to parse an external schema:

```
var schema = JSchema.Parse(@"{
  '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#',
  'properties': {
                    'address': {
                        '$ref': 'MyOtherFile.Address.json#/definitions/address'
                    }
                }
            }
            ", new JSchemaUrlResolver()); //here's the change
```